# can we use (-) sign while function declaration

Tags: php

i am working newly working on *Codeigniter* and i want to make the URL of my action like having the (-) sign that i can do with zend.
for example
localhost/project/controller/my-view

is that possible

for example i am making the controller

```
class Project extent CI_controller{

public function myview(){

}

}
```

here above myview can i write it like this (my-view) ?
Please do let me or if i can't use it like this then what to do to make the url as I want. Thank You.

Comment: @timo I tagged because i want to know that can we do the same work in c language or c++ or not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the answer you were looking for, but if you are building an API, maybe consider using swagger?

[codeigniter-swagger](https://github.com/panxp/codeigniter-swagger/blob/master/application/controllers/Welcome.php)

With this, you can than add annotations along with path:

```
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
/**
 * @package
 * @category
 * @subpackage
 *
 * @SWG\Resource(
 *  apiVersion="0.2",
 *  swaggerVersion="1.2",
 *  resourcePath="/welcome",
 *  basePath="http://localhost/auth/",
 *  produces="['application/json']"
 * )
 */
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

     /**
     *
     * @SWG\Api(
     *   path="welcome/helloword",
     *   description="Hello world",
     *   @SWG\Operations(
     *     @SWG\Operation(
     *       method="GET",
     *       summary="Hello world",
     *       notes="Returns a string",
     *       nickname="helloWord",
     *       @SWG\Parameters(
     *         @SWG\Parameter(
     *           name="username",
     *           description="your username",
     *           paramType="query",
     *           required=true,
     *           type="string"
     *         )
     *       ),
     *       @SWG\ResponseMessages(
     *          @SWG\ResponseMessage(
     *            code=400,
     *            message="Invalid username"
     *          ),
     *          @SWG\ResponseMessage(
     *            code=404,
     *            message="Not found"
     *          )
     *       )
     *     )
     *   )
     * )
     */
    public function helloWord()
    {
        echo json_encode($_GET);
    }
}
```

And you can than change the path to your needs. I am using it in symfony and it works as intended.
BR

Comment: no listen please.
i just want to make the function in the class that is action like


class Test{
public function testAction(){
echo "test";
}
};

but when i will call this it should be called like this 

localhost/project/test/test-action

it looks good instead of calling the action with uppercase letter like localhost/project/test/testAction or just making the action with all the lower case letters. like

public function testaction(){
echo "test";
}